# Missing dynamic (.so) library in fftw 2.1.5 installation

Tags: installation, libraries, fftw

I am trying to run simulations using Gadget2, an astrophysics N-body simulation package. It requires a few libraries, including fftw-2.1.5. I have installed fftw using the guidelines given in the user manual:

```
 ./configure --prefix=<PATH> --enable-typeprefix --enable-mpi
 make
 make install
 make clean
 ./configure --prefix=<PATH> --enable-float--enable-type-prefix --enable-mpi
 make
 make install
```

The two makes are to get both single and double precision files according to this [source](http://www.hpcadvisorycouncil.com/pdf/GADGET-2_Best_Practices.pdf). The install happened successfully, and I was also able to compile Gadget2.

But when I try to run Gadget2, I get the following error:

```
./Gadget2: error while loading shared libraries: libsrfftw_mpi.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file `libsrfftw_mpi.so.2` is missing in the fftw `lib` folder, even though a few download sites for fftw packages say that it is part of the contents. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the below and run your command again.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<PATH from your install command>
```

also don't forget to additionally specify `--enable-shared` for both `configure` commands.

Comment: I have already set the environment variables required. As I mentioned in the question, I checked the `lib` folder in my fftw install and there is no library by that name. I am entirely missing the file.

Comment: sorry mate, didn't look closely enough. updated my answer.